# $\Gamma(M,E)$ of rank $k$ then bundle is trivial - counterexample?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, examples-counterexamples, vector-bundles

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $n$ and let $\pi: E \rightarrow M$ be a vector bundle of rank $k$. Then one can define the $C^{\infty}(M)$-module of smooth global sections of $E$, denoted by $\Gamma(M,E)$. Now my notes say that the rank of this module is at most $k$ and equal to $k$ if and only if the bundle is trivial. Does the second statement not need some extra assumptions? Maybe orientability of $E$ or maybe only consider nowhere vanishing sections?

Consider as a counterexample the Möbius strip $M$ as a non-trivial vector bundle of rank $1$ over $S^1$. However, any global section $s: S^1 \rightarrow M$ for itself will be linearly independent. Since it has to vanish at some point $x \in S^1$ (one can find a section that vanishes at only one point) the section cannot span $\Gamma(S^1,M)$, but it will be linearly independent since any smooth function that is non-zero at $x$ is also non-zero in some neighbourhood.

So is the counterexample false or are my notes missing extra assumptions?

Comment: What's your definition of rank of a module?

Comment: Maximal number of linearly independent elements (if the rank is finite)

Comment: It sounds to me like your notes are using "rank" to mean the maximal number of linearly independent *nowhere vanishing* sections, in which case the statement would be true. This is not the standard definition: the standard definition of rank of a vector bundle is that it's the dimension of its fibers (say over a connected base).

Comment: As you say, the rank of the vector bundle is the dimension of fiber. I am concerned about the rank of the module of global sections.

Comment: Where are your notes from? As you say, with the definition of rank you just gave this is straightforwardly false. It’s true with the definition I gave, which is standard neither for vector bundles nor for modules.

Comment: It's from a problem sheet

Comment: If the rank of $\Gamma(M,E)$ is the *minimal* cardinal of a *generating* family, then it is *at least* the rank of $E$. Equality holds if and only if the bundle is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general we have:

### Proposition

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $n$ and let $E\longrightarrow M$ be a smooth vector bundle of rank $k$. Then $E$ is isomorphic to the trivial bundle if and only if there exist $k$ smooth linearly independent sections $s_1,\dots,s_k$, i.e. for every $x\in M$ the vectors $s_1(x),\dots,s_k(x)$ are linearly independent in $E_x$.

The proof is not difficult and it can be found in many books. Returning to your question, in light of this proposition, I think that the authors are saying that $\Gamma(M;E)$ has rank $r\le k$ if you can find $r$ linearly independent sections.

I hope this will help.